# Using a UITabBarController and a UINavigationController together

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

What is the best practice or good way to have with 2 tabs behave like a UINavigationController when clicking through views after the tab bar views.

Do I make a UINavigationController for each tab?

The tab bar is created like so:

```
// Create the tab bar text and images
AViewController *viewA = [[AViewController alloc] init];
BViewController *viewB = [[BViewController alloc] init];

UITabBarItem *tabA = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] tag:1];
UITabBarItem *tabB = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"B" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] tag:2]

viewA.tabBarItem = tabA;
viewB.tabBarItem = tabB;

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewA, viewB, nil];
self.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Comment: Yes, have separate `UINavigationController` in each tab. Each tab is in isolated view controller stack. They should not share any view controller hierarchy. Normally I would drag out a "Tab Bar Controller" and two "Navigation Controller" and wire the two navigation controllers as sub view controllers of the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For navigation you need to create UINavigationController for each like this

**Updated : Try now**

```
AViewController *viewA = [[AViewController alloc] init];
BViewController *viewB = [[BViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navA = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewA];
UINavigationController *navB = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewA];

UITabBarItem *tabA = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"A" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] tag:1];
UITabBarItem *tabB = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"B" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] tag:2]

tabA.tabBarItem = tabA;
tabB.tabBarItem = tabB;

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navA, navB, nil];
self.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Try this

Comment: What if the tab bar isn't in appDelegate does that matter?

Comment: Its not matter , but here you need to create uitabbarcontroller for next controller